# Python pywin32 (win32com.client) responses wrong table before Microsoft Word document ready after open()

Tags: python, ms-word, pywin32, win32com, office-automation

I found the table python read from MS Word document was wrong but can be correct if wait for a while so I make this experiment to look into the problem:

```
1. open a Word .docx document, it has total 26 tables.
2. Repeatedly print and see how many tables in this document? 
   Surprisingly this number is changing!
3. So the question is: how to know if the document is ready after .Open() ?
```

This is the code for the experiment:

```
import time 
import win32com.client
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

doc = word_app.Documents.Open(FileName = pathname, ConfirmConversions = False,NoEncodingDialog = True,Revert = True)
for i in range(40):
    print("%d:%d " % (i, doc.tables.count), end="")
    time.sleep(0.1)
doc.Close()
```

Result:

```
 0:24 1:24 2:24... there were 24 tables at first, wrong! should be 26 
12:25 13:25    ... then it became 25
26:26 27:26 28:26 ... then become 26 which is finally correct
```

Answer (score 1):

The document is ready as soon as the Open method is done. The Word object model doesn't provide any properties or method to check whether the document is loaded and initialized like in case of HTML web pages (web browsers).

Comment: It's not ready actually on some .docx files, although most are ok. As mentioned, on those specific files, read a table immediately after Open() returned you got an incorrect one until later the document really ready. Now I know this problem can be detected by comparing table count from python-docx library while, unlike win32com, python-docx always correct.

Answer (score 0):

This is my workaround

```
import time, docx, win32com.client
word_app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Word.Application")

doc_lib = docx.Document(pathname)
doc_com = word_app.Documents.Open(FileName = pathname)
while len(doc_lib.tables) != doc_com.tables.count:
    # need to wait probably a minute for doc_com to be really ready
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: docx pkg not support ```.doc file type```